# Excel merge cells, keep values, collapsing chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells

Imagine a chart that looks like this (rows 1,2,3 are merged in columns B,C,D):

```
   A    B    C    D
1 th
2 in   ##   ##   ##   
3 g1
4 th
5 in   ##   ##   ## 
6 g2
```

I want a chart that looks like this:

```
   A    B    C    D
  th  
1 in   ##   ##   ##
  g1  
  th
2 in   ##   ##   ## 
  g2
```

How do I do this? It would be awesome if the new lines in column A were maintained, but it's not a deal breaker if they're not.

Put another way, I want the data in cells A1,A2,A3 to all be in A1; A4,A5,A6 to be in A2; A7,A8,A9 to be in A3, etc.

Also, I need the data that is in B1:3 (merged) to be in B1 (unmerged); B4:6(merged) in B2(unmerged); and likewise for columns C,D,etc.

FYI, there are tens of thousands of rows.

Comment: Are you just saying you want text in cell A1 and A2 to be layered as this can be accommodated with Alt + ENTER between th and in etc.

Comment: @Antony, no. I'll explain better in the question.

Comment: If I understand the problem, you want the number in each cell of column `A` to be the same as the row number, i.e., column `A` row `25000` would be `g25000`. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: After B1:3, B4:6, etc. are unmerged, do you want to eliminate the empty rows, that is, do you want to remove rows 2, 3, 5, 6, ... for all columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using data from Sheet1,

[image: Sheet1 - Data]

create a new sheet as Sheet2

For Row 1 in cell A1 insert

```
     =Sheet1!A1 & CHAR(10) & Sheet1!A2 & CHAR(10) & Sheet1!A3
```

Using CHAR(10) is the equivalent of Pressing Alt + Enter

[image: Sheet2 cell A1]

For Row 2 Cell A2 insert

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&(INT(ROW(A1))*3+1)) & CHAR(10) & INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&(INT(ROW(A1))*3+2)) & CHAR(10) & INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&(INT(ROW(Sheet1!A1))*3+3))
```

where INT(ROW(A1))*3+1 returns the Integer of the row number of A1 multiplied by the 3 to give you every three rows with +1 to give the starting row number.
like row 4, 7, 10 ,13 etc. and Indirect function allows you to create your cell reference from text and formula.

[image: Sheet2 A2]

Remember to format your cells in column A as "Wrap text".

Select Cell B1 type`=Sheet1!B1` and use handle to drag across to populate row 1

Select Cell B2 insert

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!B"&(INT(ROW(Sheet1!B1))*3+1))
```

and use handle to drag across to populate row 2, you will now need to edit columns C D as the Indirect Column reference will not be correct as the reference is text. Change "Sheet1!B"&... to "Sheet1!C"&... for column C and "Sheet1!D"&... for column D.

Select A2 to D2 and drag fill down required number of rows

[image: Sheet2 D3]

Comment: Very clever thinking with only using the built-in functions of excel! I didn't think this was possible without using a macro.